# Can you please help to read this seal?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Can you please help to read this seal?

[image: print]

[image: seal]

I have already tried this:

Installed 說文小篆字體 .ttf font from http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/xz/swxz.ttf

And searched http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/xz/ using
Internet Explorer (seal script links do not display properly on other browsers, although they still work).

[image: http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/xz/]

But I still cannot find the right match.

Comment: I'm 80% sure that this is supposed to be 百雲初晴, but the edges of the seal are cut off so crucial parts of the characters are missing

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! 
Is it a 成语 idiom? 
What could these 4 character mean?

Comment: "The clouds are beginning to clear" ?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Having started in the study and painting of shan Shui, I also needed to conduct lengthy research into chop/seal design and cutting methods, which are what make chops such an art form, I have done some drawings based on your "seal" and the page you referenced that has quite a few conversions. If the OP is still curious I think I may have found the answer to your question. I will wait a reply to the comment I make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: 百雲初晴]

The characters look like 「百雲初晴」 (*clearing up after endless clouds*).

---

Note that the whole thing isn't really "seal script", it's really just characters written rather inconsistently.

- 「百」 is the only real thing resembling seal script
- 「雲」 is cut off at the bottom
- 「初」's left side looks like they tried to do something strange with 「衤」
- 「晴」's bottom-right component looks like it's missing the inner strokes

Comment: i would describe it as “someone with inadequate, or incorrect knowledge about seal script”. “初” is unrecognisable, and “晴” is . . . hard to guess :(

Comment: Thank you very much!